# rsync-like copy command on windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, rsync, robocopy

### tl;dr

I'm looking for a near-exact replacement for `rsync --recursive --update` on vanilla Windows.

### details

What is a command, in Windows, that works like:

input:

- a filesystem pattern (restricted to the conventional Windows type: paths with wildcards allowed only after the final separator) that resolves to a collection of files and folders
- a path to a folder (which already exists)

effect: Copies each of the items to which the input pattern resolves:

- *into* the destination folder
- only if it is newer than a same-name destination item. (Folders are evaluated recursively for timestamps of files, as with `robocopy /mir` or `xcopy /d`.)

Further requirements:

- must be a single "statement" (parentheticals area allowed, but not semicolons)
- returns nonzero on error, zero otherwise
- uses only vanilla Windows 10 (no WSL, Cygwin)

Bonus points if it also:

- works like `robocopy /purge` (that is, `rsync --delete`) for items that are folders.

Comment: It's maddening, because robocopy explicitly says it wants the triple: `<source dir> <destination dir> <file patterns>`, but if you pass `/e` or `/mir`, it interprets this as saying you *also* want to sync (all of!) `<source dir>` onto `<destination dir>`. What a broken syntax. And `xcopy` is no better, from my tests.

Comment: What's the reason for all of the restrictions?

Comment: Single-statement restriction for two reasons: First: These will be statements in an NMake recipe. NMake because the actual language I’m writing in is QMake on Windows. QMake because of legacy. Second: The only way to carry state between NMake recipe statements is through the filesystem — but I’m also trying to speedup vs invoking Powershell to call `Copy-Item -Recurse`, and using the filesystem for bookkeeping here would foil the speedup. Vanilla Windows for political reasons — this is for team SOP, and I’m not the boss, so I want to minimize the number of things I’m asking them to accept.

Comment: Why single statement? Why not a script?

Comment: Same thing — slowdown due to filesystem reads. (Although, I must admit, I didn’t speed-test that.)

Comment: I don't mean a script that copies everything: I mean why not a script that contains the appropriate robocopy/xcopy commands? And why not a PowerShell script that contains the neede commands?

Comment: I think you’re right that that would have been worth a try: write a script to implement `rsync --recursive --update --delete`. What I meant by “slowdown due to filesystem reads”, was avoiding reading a script file each invocation. But perhaps it still would have been a net speedup, if not for the fundamental problem I mention in my answer — which led to me aborting the task of allowing wildcards to be file/folder agnostic: There seems to be no way to do this on Windows without expanding wildcards, which seems to insurmountably cause slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the one-liner equivalent, on Windows, of `rsync --recursive --update --delete <FILE PATTERN> <DESTINATION PARENT DIR>/`, without invoking Powershell (which would have killed my throughput in my application) is:

`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion && FOR %%F IN (<FILE PATTERN>) DO (IF NOT EXIST %%F\NUL ( (xcopy %%F <DESTINATION PARENT DIR> /D /R /Y /I) || EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL! ) ) && FOR /D %%D IN (<FILE PATTERN>) DO (IF EXIST %%D\NUL ( (robocopy %%D <DESTINATION PARENT DIR>\%%~nxD /MIR /PURGE || IF !ERRORLEVEL! LSS 8 cd. ) || EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL!) )`

To explain this, I'll break it up into lines with comments:

```
REM Stupidly, by default, Windows evaluates %variables% in loop blocks *before* the block executes.
REM   This line makes var evaluation instead act the way everyone would actually want and expect,
REM   although only when you use !variable! syntax.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Stupidly, `FOR` with no params means: "expand wildcards only to files (not folders),
REM   and loop over the resulting list".
REM   But even this doesn't do what you expect, because folders *will* be retained
REM   in the expanded list -- the filtering *only* happens for wildcarded elements of the pattern.
REM   (See the note further below.)
REM Stupidly, Windows requires `%%` for loop vars in .bat files, but `%` at the command-line.
REM   (Be advised.)
FOR %%F IN (<FILE PATTERN>) DO (
    REM As mentioned above, the non-folders-only version of `FOR` *does* let folders through,
    REM   so we have to manually filter anway.
    REM The way in Windows (without calling Powershell) to check if a filename is
    REM   not a folder name is to do the weird construct below.
    IF NOT EXIST %%F\NUL (
        (xcopy %%F <DESTINATION PARENT DIR> /D /R /Y /I) || EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL!
    )
REM `FOR /D` has the same unintuitive behavior described above for `FOR`,
REM   but switching the role of folders and non-folders.
) && FOR /D %%D IN (<FILE PATTERN>) DO (
    REM Ditto and vice-versa prev notes.
    IF EXIST %%D\NUL (
        REM `robocopy` returns exit codes 0-7 on success.
        REM   It's like Microsoft doesn't want its tools to be scriptable.
        REM   So we qualify the exit code.
        REM `CD.` is the best way I know to simulate the plain old POSIX `true`.
        (
            robocopy %%D <DESTINATION PARENT DIR>\%%~nxD /MIR /PURGE || IF !ERRORLEVEL! LSS 8 cd.
        ) || EXIT /B !ERRORLEVEL!
    )
)
```

In my case, throughput was no better than the calls to `powershell -Command "Copy-Item -Recurse -Force"` that did unnecessary copying and had the overhead of launching Powershell, because the replacement code above invokes `xcopy` individually on every item in the expanded file pattern. No, I couldn't store the expanded list in a var and pass it to a single invocation of `xcopy`, because of the Windows command line length limit. And we must do the expansion because we must discriminate files vs folders, because the syntax of `xcopy` is inconsistent between files and folders, and so is the syntax of `robocopy`. In 2021, Windows still lacks a file/folder-agnostic copy command that does recursion and update-only. So, in the end, I couldn't actually do what I was trying to do, and I had to force my clients to designate which patterns were for files and which for folders.

Comment: FTR, copying entire files is definitely not the same as how `rsync` behaves, i.e.: transferring delta information only (which makes a substantial difference in efficiency for very large files).

Answer (score 0):

Install Cygwin - it has a rsync package available, so you get rsync.exe

I have been using it for years to sync disk to disk on localhost, to another windows host and to/from a ubuntu host - works perfectly fine :-)

Paths have to be specified like this: /cygdrive/C/...

Comment: I explicit said no Cygwin. Must work on empty Windows, sadly.

Comment: good suggestion from somebody ariving here by reading the title.